# limit of sum of abs of sine of positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

help prove that $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|\sin(k)| = \frac{2}{\pi}$$.

---

I tried to convert it to an integral with an abs of chebyshev polynomail, but cannot go further.

Answer (score 1):

The quantities $\{ e^{icn} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $c/\pi$ is irrational, are equidistributed on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. The quantity $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin (ck)|$$
is therefore just the mean absolute value of the real part of $e^{icn}$, which can be computed (thanks to equidistribution) as an integral on the circle as $$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |\sin (\theta)|\, d\theta = \frac{2}{\pi}.$$ Your first equation is just the special case $c = 1$.

Comment: appreciate your hints. the second equation is wrong so I editted it and removed it.